# .htaccess redirect to HTTP on Drupal 7 site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

I'm having problems with a redirect from https to http. The reason I'm doing this is that the server is having performance issues and thus having a caching server on top of Apache (listening to port 80).

So to reduce the load, I want to redirect all requests that don't have a cookie (cookie only accepts https) and don't go to the login page (/user) to http.

This is my .htaccess file, I removed everything else for testing, there are no further rewrite rules. The third RewriteRule is from Drupal, sending all requests to index.php.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # Rewrite http to https for /user.
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/user
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/user [R=301,L]
  #
  # Rewrite https to http for anonymous.
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !SSESS
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/user
  RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=307,L]
  #
  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now the redirect to https for /user works fine. But then https://domain/user returns the following response header (when having no cookie):

```
Status: HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: http://domain/index.php
```

So if the second rule fails, it wants to redirect to /index.php with 307?
Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Thanks a lot,
mpj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your second rule's URI condition to

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\ /+user [NC]
```

Your current rule is redirecting `index.php` as well, on the subsequent rewrite cycle.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Any ideas why {REQUEST_URI} doesn't work here? Yes, a rewrite to index.php is correct, it just shouldn't use a redirect as the index.php looses the information of the current address then (it's handling all requests).

Comment: When your last rewrite happens you may think it's all done but no, Apache passes index.php for another rewrite cycle. In this final cycle your rule request_uri !^/user matches since the previous rewrite changed it to index.php and you get a 307 redirect now. By matching on the_request instead we avoid this rewrite problem.